# Google Analytics User Id tracking not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have gone through tons of tutorials, SO posts and even the Google docs. I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to track all user interaction after the user logs into our application. I created a `User Id` enabled view in the Admins section called "User ID View" and I have another view called "All Website Data" which tracks by `Client ID`.

I placed the GA tracker initialization code in a file called Footer.js that is rendered on every page in the application. This allows me to track "page views" for all pages in the app. Then I placed the User Id tracking code in a file called Login.js, on the success callback of an AJAX request that is used for authentication. This should allow me to associate any "page views" and "events" with a specific user once they are logged in. I also have "event" trackers sprinkled throughout the application to track button clicks.

My issue is that **ALMOST** all the "page views" and "events" are being tracked on the "All Website Data" view (associated with the `Client Id`) instead of the "User Id View" view. The only "event" and "page view" correctly tracked in "User Id View" view are the ones included in the authentication AJAX call's success callback. **I want all post-authentication events and page views to be tracked in the "User ID View" view and that is not happening.**

I have attached the code below hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I really appreciate the help.

**Footer.cshtml:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

**Login.js**

```
$.ajax({
        data: ko.toJSON(myData), type: 'POST', url: http://www.example.org, 
        success: function (data) {
          window.location.href = data.redirect;
          ga('set', 'userId', data.userId);
          ga('send', 'event', 'authentication', 'User has logged in');
          ga('send', 'pageview');
        },
        error: function (request) { handleSubmitError(request.responseText); }
      });
```

Comment: Anyone have an idea? I can provide any other details needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think after `window.location.href` is not work, because the page has been redirected.

Try to put it to `setTimeout` queue after `ga('send', 'pageview')`  .